# java.io.EOFException: \n not found, while reading from BufferedReader

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat

I am trying to read rss feed but getting below error when tried to read from BufferedReader.

[Error stack trace [screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlQvx.png)

Following is the method which is reading and converting rss feed

```
private String downloadXML(String urlPath){
        StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlPath);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(TAG, "downloadXML: The response code was " + responseCode);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            int charRead;
            char [] bufferRead = new char[500];
            while (true){
                charRead = reader.read(bufferRead);

                if(charRead<0){
                    break;
                }
                if(charRead>0){
                    xml.append(String.copyValueOf(bufferRead, 0, charRead));
                }
            }
            reader.close();

            return xml.toString();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "downloadXML: Invalid URL " + e.getMessage() );
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "downloadXML: IO exception " + e.getMessage() );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "downloadXML: SecurityEception " + e.getMessage() );
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Line 62 is `charRead = reader.read(bufferRead);`
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: try to change `while(true)` with `while(reader.readLine() != null)`

Comment: I tried but got the same error.

Comment: Try to change line number : 10 to 22 with this code `String str;
        while ((str=reader.readLine()) != null) {
            xml.append(str);
        }
        reader.close();`

Comment: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0

I found this exception after the changes you suggested

Comment: This looks like a major bug in Android. It doesn't have any business reading lines if you aren't, and it doesn't have any business complaining about a missing liinefeed either. NB `charRead` cannot possibly be zero unless `buffer` is zero length, which it isn't. Don't write pointless tests.

Comment: @RahulSonpaliya Why? Your first suggestion is not a valid way to read an entire file.

Comment: @EJP , What will you suggest me to get my code working?

Answer (score 4):

Our project encountered this similar problem. And our solution is to add a configuration for http header.
addHeader("Connection", "close")

Comment: You save my life